# How to update joomla modules from repository?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

i created module and put it into joomla repository. I created the update for that module, and put into repository too. Into my xml file i write some line to be install tags:

```
 <install version="1.5" type="module" client="site" method="upgrade">
```

I known how to updated extentions in joomla ([Update extentions](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_an_update_server))

```
<extension type="component" version="2.5.0" method="upgrade">
```

But how to update the modules? In admin part i can't see my update from repository. Can you help me, or can you give some links where i can read about only modules update in Joomla.

Thank!

Comment: Have you added in the `<update>` tags and linked it to your external XML file?

Comment: No, i didn't do this, can you write simple example?

Comment: Tell me should I insert <code><extension type="component" version="2.5.0" method="upgrade"></code> in my module? Because module it's be a not extensions. Or i need to write some <code><extension type="module" version="2.5.0" method="upgrade"></code>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You firstly need to add the following to your XML file for your module:

```
<updateservers>
    <server type="extension" name="Name of Module" priority="1">http://www.example.com/update.xml</server>
</updateservers>
```

Then, create a new XML file called **update.xml** (if you want to call it something else, then be sure to change the name in the code above) and add the following code to it:

```
<updates>
    <update>
       <name>Name of Module</name>
       <description>description goes here</description>
       <element>mod_my_module</element>
       <type>module</type>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
       <downloads>
           <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">http://www.example.com/module.zip</downloadurl>
       </downloads>
       <maintainer>Company Name</maintainer>
       <maintainerurl>http://www.example.com</maintainerurl>
       <targetplatform name="joomla" version="2.5"/>
       <client>0</client>
       <client_id>0</client_id>
    </update>
<updates>
```

Every time you want to release an update, you simply need to duplicate the `<update>` tags and everything inside it and put it above the previous one. So here would be an example of version **1.0.0** and **1.1.0**

```
<updates>
    <update>
       <name>Name of Module</name>
       <description>description goes here</description>
       <element>mod_my_module</element>
       <type>module</type>
       <version>1.1.0</version>
       <downloads>
           <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">http://www.example.com/module.zip</downloadurl>
       </downloads>
       <maintainer>Company Name</maintainer>
       <maintainerurl>http://www.example.com</maintainerurl>
       <targetplatform name="joomla" version="2.5"/>
       <client>0</client>
       <client_id>0</client_id>
    </update>
    <update>
       <name>Name of Module</name>
       <description>description goes here</description>
       <element>mod_my_module</element>
       <type>module</type>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
       <downloads>
           <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">http://www.example.com/module.zip</downloadurl>
       </downloads>
       <maintainer>Company Name</maintainer>
       <maintainerurl>http://www.example.com</maintainerurl>
       <targetplatform name="joomla" version="2.5"/>
       <client>0</client>
       <client_id>0</client_id>
    </update>
<updates>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's simple and perfect! Thank you very much;-)

Comment: Does it work with local server? I tried to implement it to my module in my localhost with joomla 3.0, but joomla never recognize the update

Comment: It works fine for me on a local server using Wampserver. I'm not sure about Xampp as I refuse to use it, so you will need to check your localhost setting to allow outgoing requests like this

Comment: @Lodder I tried to install one of your module, JJ Social Image , that uses updater, and I got this message on Joomla 2.5 : Update: :Extension: Could not open   http://www.joomjunk.co.uk/updates/socialimages_update.xml but JCE working fine. see https://www.dropbox.com/s/yaxos8hqd3nymnz/65ita.jpg?dl=0 . In Joomla 3.3 nothing happened (no update recognized)

Comment: @Lodder fyi I don't have old version of JJ Social images so I changed the JJ Social image version on its xml file on my localhost to make it recognizes an update

Comment: @Lodder ok it looks like the problem is with my local installation. I have made a new install and it now works properly. Thanks for the reply. I have voted up your answer.

Comment: @dreamexploded - Glad you got it working :) Just be sure to request support for one of my extensions on JJ Forum rather than Stackoverflow as the question asked here was regarding updating an extension from a repository such as Github ;)

Comment: Hi there. Please help. I am concerned about the tag 'client'. What value should I use for a plugin? @dreamexploded

Comment: @Daydah you dont need to use `client` for plugins. It's only for modules and templates

Comment: @Lodder actually you do - folder and client tags are compulsory for plugins. I just found out. "...Plugins and front-end modules are automatically installed with a client of 0 (site), but you will need to specify the client in an update or it will default to 1 (administrator) and then found update would not be shown because it would not match any extension..." from https://docs.joomla.org/Deploying_an_Update_Server